# restrict javascript window.onerror to errors only in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have added a means to log events that happen at the browser to my server side logs:

This sends a message to my server (used just as I would use  console.log to log key events during normal operation)

```
function remoteConsoleLog(msgToLog, msgDesc) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/php/log_javascript_events.php',
    data: JSON.stringify({UA: navigator.userAgent, MSG: msgToLog, MSGDESC: msgDesc}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });
}
```

And this is a wrapper for the above to capture other errors (based on [this](https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-even-on-chrome-and-firefox/)):

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    remoteConsoleLog(errorMsg, 'window onerror');
}
```

This works well and I get all the events I expect in my server log file. However, the problem is that I'm getting some errors I don't expect from the window.onerror handler such as generic "**Script error**" (I have seen this may be a CORS issue) and other very specific errors e.g.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DealPly is not defined

(which appears to relate to a browser plugin unrelated to my site).

My site uses some external JS files such as JQuery and the like. Is there any way to only log errors generated by the javascript file that contains my logging, i.e. exclude third party errors - or is that even a good thing to try to do?

Comment: based on replies below I just modified the wrapper - remoteConsoleLog(errorMsg, 'window onerror ' + url); - to log the script name and will filter server side

Comment: did you figure out what was causing the `DealPly is not defined` error? we started seeing it a lot for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i believe the URL shows the name of the script, so you could check that against your own script files

```
var mySripts = ["a.js", "b.js"];
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    //or however the url is formatted
    if (myScripts.indexOf(url) > -1) {
         remoteConsoleLog(errorMsg, 'window onerror');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the URL?

Comment: its availible in the event handler you posted yourself (the second argument)

Comment: perfect! I simulated an error and it was logged with along with my script name (I decided to just pass the url along to the server logs so I can see all errors can filter server side). I'll have to wait not for some actual errors to occur now.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i can think of is checking if the `url` is the same as your `js` file and check if the `errorMsg` is different than "script error".

Something like this:

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    if(errorMsg.indexOf('Script error.') > -1 || url != "yourfile.js") {
        return;
    }
    remoteConsoleLog(errorMsg, 'window onerror');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future visitors DealPly is an Adware, or virus if you like. So the problem is probably that your visitors has this adware and that there's something wrong with the script it's using. Just a guess though.